# Cannot update Tango Core - "Package file was not signed correctly"

Tags: google-project-tango

Got my Tango tablet last night and tried to get it going by installing required packages. Updating "Project Tango Core" app failed. Here's the error I get:

[image: Error: Package file was not signed correctly]

Anybody else seen this and know how to fix it?
Here's some info that may be required:

[image: system info and versions]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the build number that you have pictured above, this is an old OS build. In order to fix this issue you need to perform an update on the system software (Settings->About Tablet->System Updates).

Once you have updated to the latest software version, currently Cantor, this issue should resolve itself.

Edit : If your tablet does not see the update you may need to perform a factory data reset (Settings->Backup and Reset->Factory Data Reset).

Cheers,
Chase

Comment: Even though the tablet was showing "system is up to date", after I let it sit for a day, it finally showed "there's an update available". After updating, everything worked fine.

Comment: I had a similar experience when I had downloaded the system update, but it had not yet installed (due to low battery).  When system update was installed, the core update finished without issue.