# New Tango device OTA not upgrading

Tags: google-project-tango

New device unboxed a couple of days ago.  Cannot use OTA to upgrade, says current software is up to date even though it is not.  Without a current kernel I cannot download tango core, etc. So the device is basically non-functional (other than a plain tablet :-)) out of the box.

Same problem as this question:
[Cannot update Tango Core - "Package file was not signed correctly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450740/cannot-update-tango-core-package-file-was-not-signed-correctly)

Factory resets did not fix the problem.  Unlike the previous question, waiting 48 hours provided no resolution.  Several users on the Google+ developer group are having similar issues with this batch of devices, so this seems to be a common problem

Thanks!

Comment: From @Pranshu: Hi I also have the same problem. Not able to update the device and Project Tango Core. Did factory reset several times. I have been waiting from last 3 days.

If anyone at Google is listening, please resolve this issue asap.

Comment: You're doing the factory reset from the menu that appears when you boot holding down the vol up,down, and power buttons ?  If so, I got nothing, sorry - if not, the menu you get is handy for some issues

Comment: same here, several days past, no update at all.

Answer (score 2):

We had an error in our OTA server configuration that we fixed this morning. This might take some time to propagate, but you should start seeing updates soon. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. 
To critique or request clarification from an author, 
leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, 
and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.

Comment: @Ghost - it rather specifically answers the question -  note the tag says that this is a prototype system from google, the specific question involved the OTA server, and the specific answer involved the fact that said server is now fixed - in what way would you see that as not an answer to a question ?

Comment: The issue is resolved.  Thank you for your speedy fix

Comment: @BrianSumma - please check as answered - if only so to not further bait the nannies that don't read the tag description  :-)